# DNS / Active Directory SRV Records

Tags: active-directory

Im trying to understand how SRV records should be getting returned when attempting to join a workstation to a domain.

We have a bunch of sites all with different subnets. We have matched the subnet with a site and added the only DCs available to that site. We have network isolation between all sites so not all Domain Controllers can be reached.

When i do a domain join with the UI of the server, it sometimes fails and when looking at the error its returning a bunch of DCs that are not specific to the site the subnet is linked to.

So it looks like the Server is trying to domain join to DCs that are not reachable?

Is my understanding correct that when a Server looks up the SRV records to domain join, the list of DCs being returned should be from the Site its linked too, or is it correct to be returned a random list of DCs - The current list its returning is seems random in that it doesn't return all DCs, but what looks like a random selection.

The problem i have is that not all DCs are reachable, so if the returned list is random then i will need to enable network connectivity between all DCs which is going to be really difficult cause we have something like 50 sites.